# RegisterBroadcastReceiver in Manifest.xml setting or by implement source code

Tags: android

I have little concern about **register BroadcastReceiver**: Because Android support quite flexible, it allow BroadcastReceiver register by 2 method: In Manifest.xml setting and Via implement source code:

**Example:**

❶ **Via Manifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="YourBroadcastMesssage" />
</intent-filter>
```

❷ **Register thought implement of source code:**

```
IntentFilter filter = IntentFilter("BroadcastMessage");
filter.addAction("BroadcastMessage");
context.registerReceiver(BroadcastListener, filter);

enter code here
```

★I think one of difference is unregister able:

1. Implement ❶ mean **always** handler registed broadcast message.
2. Implement ❷ for in case don't want to handler Broadcast message, can unregister that broadcast message

★**Question:**

I still don't known exactly when to use ❶ or ❷ and which is better?

Comment: good question and excellent formatting :]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO, you must register the BroadcastReceiver from code when you want to execute things in that activity directly once the broadcast has been caught (e.g. finish the activity).

When you want to perform other kind of tasks which don't require the activity, use the XML setting (e.g. launching a Toast to show some info).

Comment: Hie Christian, this is the signature to register the broadcast - context.registerReceiver(BroadcastListener, filter);, while there exist one more method with regiterReceiver(BroadcastListener, permission, filter, handler).. You can help me how to pass permission there?