# How to use a BroadcastReceiver to update two activities?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a application that has just two activities, the main activity and a PreferenceActivity.  When there is a change in states (Aeroplane mode being turned on or off, the GPS being turned on and off, etc ), I want to update both activities.

I need to update some variables and the UI only when the app is active so I guess it is better to register the receivers in code rather than in the application manifest.

As I dont want to replicate code in each activity, I tried putting the BroadcastReceiver in its own class.  However then I find I am not able to register the BroadcastReceiver.  Is there a way around this problem?

Thankyou, Mel

```
public class melsBigListener {


IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE");
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //TO DO Update both my main activity and the preference activity
        //TO DO deal with different intents via switch statement... 
    } 

}; 

//registering as receiver(like below) can not work
//registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);}
```

[Relevant post:RegisterBroadcastReceiver in Manifest.xml setting or by implement source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112182/registerbroadcastreceiver-in-manifest-xml-setting-or-by-implement-source-code)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest registering the receiver in the manifest and use it to alter variables stored in a preferences file (whether the app is running or not) and then query the preferences for state when needed.

But you could extend `Application` and register the receiver in code in the `Application.onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter); should be in some method.
```

`melsBigListener`  should extends activity or you need to pass Activity Context to this class and use it for registerReceiver.

Instead of doing this silly stuff it is better to write register receiver in menifest file.

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceivers should work as an extended class that is registered to the phone using the manifest file. I'm not too sure how it will work as an instantiated class inside an activity. judging by your code so far, the intent will never even be received by the Activity and your BigListener class because the intent filter was never declared in the manifest.

To solve your problem:
1. create a myBroadcastReceiver, extending from BroadcastReceiver, declaring the necessary intents in the manifest
2. create a myApplication, extending from Application
3. use your Activities' onCreate, onDestroy, onStartCmd, onPause etc to manage the "only when the app is active" part, by toggling a variable in myApplication.
4. use myBroadcastReceiver to read off the variable in (3) whenever the intent is received, to decide if you "need to update some variables" and update accordingly. Since these variables are shared by your 2 Activities, the variables should be put inside the myApplication class